# Read a file and store its contents in a variable

Tags: macros, conditionals, filesystem-access

I am trying to implement single sourcing such that same document can be conditionally typeset for number of purposes. This is what I would like to do.

```
\IfFileExists{../DecMaker.txt}{
    var x = DecMaker.txt %the file will contain a single digit number
    if x = 0{
        \newcommand{\product}{Windows}
    }
    if x = 1{
        \newcommand{\product}{Linux}
    }
    if x = 2{
        \newcommand{\product}{Mac}
    }
    \product\ computer bought from ThisRandomBrand is amazing!
}
{
    Go and buy a \product\ computer from ThisRandomBrand!!
}
```

I read up a bit about `etoolbox` and tried to use the `\iftoggle` command. Its complicating the matters with multiple ifs.

Please let me know if you need more details.

**EDIT**: I intend to use the above variable in numerous other places in my document. E.g.

```
if x = 0{
        Press the power button and pray that you don't get a blue screen
    }
if x = 1{
        Congratulations for forwarding the evolution!!
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`catchfile`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/catchfile). It's also better to separate the reading of the auxiliary file from the definition part, so you can easily reuse the code for the OS. The macro `\newOScommand` has five arguments: the name of the command to define and the four branches as shown in the example.

```
\usepackage{catchfile}

\IfFileExists{../DecMaker.txt}
 {\CatchFileEdef{\OSnumber}{../DecMaker.txt}{\endlinechar=-1 }}
 {\def\OSnumber{-1}}

\newcommand{\newOScommand}[5]{%
  \ifcase\OSnumber\relax
    \newcommand{#1}{#2}\or
    \newcommand{#1}{#3}\or
    \newcommand{#1}{#4}\else
    \newcommand{#1}{#5}%
\fi

\newOScommand{\product}{Windows}{Linux}{Mac}{No computer}
```

Comment: Wow!! Thanks! Just the thing I needed! Sadly, I already accepted TH's answer.

Comment: @manucpp You can change your mind and accept this one if it's the best for you. I told you to accept the answer but I forgot to tell you to wait a little for better ones.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what the right way to do this with the LaTeX macros like `\IfFileExists`, but using the low-level TeX primitives this is easy to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newread\makerfile
\begin{document}
\openin\makerfile=../DecMaker.txt
\ifeof\makerfile
    Go and buy a computer from ThisRandomBrand!!
\else
    \read\makerfile to\makerline
    \closein\makerfile
    \edef\product{%
        \ifcase\makerline
            Windows%
        \or Linux%
        \or Mac%
        \fi
    }
    \product\ computer bought from ThisRandomBrand is amazing!
\fi
\end{document}
```

It tries to open `../DecMaker.txt` and if that fails, it outputs the "Go and buy..." line. Otherwise, it defines `\product` to `Windows`, `Linux`, or `Mac` and outputs the "Linux computer..." line (for example).

I don't know (and cannot easily test) what happens if this file is actually run on a Windows machine. In particular, I don't know if `../DecMaker.txt` is treated as the path you want.

If `DecMaker.txt` were moved to the same directory, then this should work correctly everywhere.

Comment: It works!! Thank you! However, I'd greatly appreciate if you could elaborate on the happenings. What is `\makerfile` and `\makerline`, for instance.

Comment: @manucpp, the question asks about reading a file and storing its contents. My answer really only takes the first line of the file, but since you said the file would only have only a single digit, this should work.

Comment: I intend to use the above variable in numerous other places in my document. Where is it being stored? Also, how do I begin learning more about TeX primitives? They seem to have answers on most of my problems.

Comment: @manucpp, it's stored in `\product`. Isn't that what your pseudocode is showing? The two best places to learn about TeX primitives are _The TeXbook_ and _TeX by Topic_. The latter is more of a reference, but it is free. Just run `texdoc texbytopic`. I consult _TeX by Topic_ all the time when answering questions on TeX SX.

Comment: I have added an edit to the question. Please help me understand how to use `\product` in a scenario described by the edit.

Comment: Oh, the input from the file got written to `\makerline`. You can change the name to something more appropriate for your use case. Note that it contains both the digit and a trailing space token. Any place TeX expects a number (e.g., `\ifnum`, `\ifcase`, and `\count0=`) allows an optional space token to follow the number. The space is used to mark the end of the number. If you don't want the space, you can use `{\endlinechar=-1 \global\read\makerfile to\makerline}`.

Comment: @manucpp sorry, I missed your initial comment. `\makerfile` is a small integer that represents one of TeX's 16 input streams. `\openin\makerfile=file.ext` tries to open the given file and associates it with the integer assigned to `\makerfile`. `\makerline` is just a macro that gets set to the contents of the next line to be read from the input stream. So `\read\makerfile to\makerline` reads the first line from the file and assigns it to `\makerline`. You could read the second line by using another `\read\makerfile to\foo`.

Answer (score 6):

Run with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
local x = {"Windows","Linux","Darwin"}

function FileTest(filename)
  local f=assert(io.open(filename, "r"))
  local t=f:read()
  f:close()
  if t then
    return x[tonumber(t)].." computer bought from ThisRandomBrand is amazing!"
  else
    return "Go and buy a computer from ThisRandomBrand!!"
  end
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\Test[1]{\directlua{tex.print(FileTest("#1"))}}

\begin{document}
  \Test{../DecMaker.txt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am currently using `xelatex`. How separated is `lualatex` from `xelatex`?

Comment: `lualatex` has the same font handling as `xelatex` but more flexibility in using the script language Lua